# How do I find what is the last number in a street?

Tags: google-maps

I want to find the last number in a street in Google maps API.
Is it that easy?
Or, if that is impossible, can I find if a street number exist?

Answer (score 3):

There's a guy that keeps advertising Smarty Streets, try them, otherwise, here's some pseudo-code

http://smartystreets.com/

1. enter random number between 0 and 1000
2. run geocoder; you might end up with a result that's in another part of town. So you need some kind of error verification or catch those errors thrown by the geocoder
3. increase number by 100 or 500
4. run geocoder again, remembering to throttle it by 0.5 seconds or more with `setTimeout` or some kind of sleep function. Otherwise, *OVER_QUERY_LIMIT* error will appear.
5. repeat from #1

*Suggestion from the Comments (Jason):*

Start with a middle (known to exist) number and search forwards and backwards, or double and halve the numbers. It's a great suggestion.

Example: You know #2000 exists, so check #500 and #4000 and see which throws an error

Comment: I would instead use something like one-sided binary search: Start with 1 and geocode, then try 2, then 4, then 8, and keep doubling until you don't get a result - and binary search for the last valid address.

Comment: How does that answer the question? Please explain.

Comment: The question is broad and open-ended, so my answer is also broad and open-ended; it is asking if something is possible or not, and the only way that I know how to answer the question is through trial-and-error

Comment: Smarty Streets... they want a lot of money... Is there something in Maps API?

Comment: SmartyStreets has a free plan. Just depends on how many requests you plan on making.